# valgrind leaks detected no matter what

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind, clang++

Even when I compile and run a program like this:

```
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following valgrind errors when I run `valgrind --leak-check=yes ./a.out`

```
==26391== LEAK SUMMARY:
==26391==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==26391==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==26391==      possibly lost: 72 bytes in 3 blocks
==26391==    still reachable: 200 bytes in 6 blocks
==26391==         suppressed: 18,528 bytes in 153 blocks
==26391== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==26391== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
```

I am compiling with `clang++ test.cpp`. I am at a total loss for how to fix this.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried "==26391== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all"?

Comment: On Linux I have possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks. The "still reachable" seems to relate to some Linux libraries.

Comment: Report it on your distro's bugtracker for the glibc.  This is definitely not your fault.

Answer (score 1):

Valgrind manual has the following about possibly lost

> This means that a chain of one or more pointers to the block has been
>   found, but at least one of the pointers is an interior-pointer. This
>   could just be a random value in memory that happens to point into a
>   block, and so you shouldn’t consider this ok unless you know you have
>   interior-pointers.

This implies that all reported `possibly lost` occurrence are not leak. This need to be confirmed by code perusal to check leak.

For your particular case, we know there is no leak happening in your code. 
You might like to rerun `valgrind` again with `--leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all`